Function that finds how many times can a triangle be divided in half if the minimum allowed size (area) of the triangle is given
Find how many times ($n$) a triangle with a known area $S_{ABC}$ can be divided in half so that the area of the smallest triangle is not less than the allowed value $S_{min}$.
Both $S_{ABC}$, $S_{min}$ values are positive numbers, not necessarily integers. $n$ - is an integer.
Similarly to the other question Function that finds how many times n can be divided in half
I was able to derive the following formula:
$n = Math.floor( Math.log_2( Math.ceil(S_{ABC}/S_{min})))$
This formula does not always give the correct result.
For example:
$
S_{ABC} = 193.019\\
S_{min} = 32\\
n = Math.floor( Math.log_2( Math.ceil(193.019/32))) = 2
$
If we take half of the value of $S_{ABC}$, then $n$ should decrease by one:
$
S_{DEF} = \frac{1}{2} \times 193.019 = 96.51\\
S_{min} = 32\\
n = Math.floor( Math.log_2( Math.ceil(96.51/32))) = 2
$
I can't figure out where the mistake is.
How to determine the correct function?

What does it mean for a triangle to be divided in half?

The problem is that the inner Math.ceil function should not be there.
As it is, if you try any values where $S_{ABC}>S_\min$ (e.g. $10$ and $9$) then $\mathtt{Math.ceil}(S_{ABC}/S_\min)$ will be at least $2$ (it's an integer greater than $1$), so after taking the logarithm and then a floor you will always get at least $1$. But you can't divide a triangle of area $10$ in half so that each part has area at most $9$.
Without the ceiling, the formula works. This is because after $k$ divisions you have triangles of area $S_{ABC}/2^k$. This is at least $S_\min$ if and only if $k\leq \log_2(S_{ABC}/S_\min)$. Of course, $k$ also needs to be an integer, which is where the Math.floor comes from.
